# How to programmatically generate arguments to user-defined function in GNU Make?

Tags: makefile, metaprogramming, gnu-make, user-defined-functions

I am attempting a small project using meta-programming in GNU Make, and I have a specialized need to programmatically create all of the arguments that will be passed to some of my user-defined functions.

```
override CMD:=foo

define foo =
  $(info You have called function [$0] with $$1='$1' and $$2='$2')
endef

# this doesn't work
override ARGS:=bar,baz
$(call $(CMD),$(ARGS))

# this doesn't work either
override COMMA:=,
override ARGS:=bar;baz
$(call $(CMD),$(subst ;,$(COMMA),$(ARGS)))

$(info ---)
$(info CMD was '$(CMD)')
$(info ARGS was '$(ARGS)')
$(info COMMA was '$(COMMA)')
```

The problem I run into is that GNU Make is smarter than I want it to be, and can discern the difference between a syntactical comma, and a comma within a variable or immediate value:

```
You have called function [foo] with $1='bar,baz' and $2=''
You have called function [foo] with $1='bar,baz' and $2=''
---
CMD was 'foo'
ARGS was 'bar;baz'
COMMA was ','
```

Are there any sneaky ways to do this so that my 'foo' function sees $1 as 'bar', and $2 as 'baz'?   Or will I have to abandon this approach altogether?

**NOTE1:** space delimiters and `$(foreach)` is not an adequate solution, as that will just be kicking the can down the road.  Ultimately, I need foo to be fooled into thinking it has been passed the expected number of arguments.  (Although, I am not opposed to solutions that use `$(foreach)` as some intermediate step.)

**NOTE2:** While I don't want to discourage solutions that rely on the programmatic generation of a secondary makefile to be included at the bottom of this one-- as that might be useful to other SO readers-- I am not personally interested in any such approach.

Comment: try `$(eval $$(call $$(CMD),$(ARGS)))`

Comment: You are my hero.  (Also: why didn't I think of that?)  Make this an answer!

Comment: The key understanding to take away here is that make will always split up the arguments to functions _before_ it expands anything.  That's how it knows that embedded commas, etc. are not delimiters (which usually you don't want them to be).  It also allows you to hide all sorts of otherwise-special characters from make functions, by putting them into variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eval will save you from unnecessary includes:

```
$(eval $$(call $$(CMD),$(ARGS)))
```